# Angular Material Dialog panelClass Wont Update

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I'm working with an Angular Material Dialog Box and I'm trying to make the background a custom color.

This question has been asked quite a few times and I've tried to apply the answer but it doesn't seem to work. Specifically, it doesn't appear that the `panelClass` of the dialog container is updating. Below is the component opening the dialog, the _theming.scss file, and the HTML element

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/AuthenticationPackage/core/auth.service'
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { FactiondialogComponent } from './factiondialog/factiondialog.component';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-factions2',
  templateUrl: './factions2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./factions2.component.scss']
})
export class Factions2Component implements OnInit {


  constructor( public authService: AuthService,
            public dialog: MatDialog ) { }

  ngOnInit(){  }



  openDialog(faction): void{
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig()

    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.data = {faction};
    dialogConfig.panelClass = ".faction-dialog";


    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FactiondialogComponent, dialogConfig)

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            console.log("dialog closed");
        });
}
}
```

The _theming.scss section:

```
@mixin mat-dialog-theme($theme) {
  $background: map-get($theme, background);
  $foreground: map-get($theme, foreground);

  .faction-dialog{
    background-color:rgb(28, 31, 32)
}

  .mat-dialog-container {
    @include _mat-theme-elevation(24, $theme);
    background: mat-color($background, dialog);
    color: mat-color($foreground, text);
  }
}

@mixin mat-dialog-typography($config) {
  .mat-dialog-title {
    @include mat-typography-level-to-styles($config, title);
  }
}
```

This is the markup generated and but it does not include my custom class.

```
<mat-dialog-container aria-modal="true" class="mat-dialog-container ng-tns-c12-2 ng-trigger ng-trigger-dialogContainer ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1" id="mat-dialog-0" role="dialog" style="transform: none;"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-portal": ""
}--><app-factiondialog _nghost-lda-c13="" class="ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-lda-c13="" class="dialogCard"><h2 _ngcontent-lda-c13="" class="mat-dialog-title">The Harpers</h2><mat-dialog-content _ngcontent-lda-c13="" class="mat-typography mat-dialog-content"><p _ngcontent-lda-c13="">
SOME CONTENT THAT DOESNT MATTER TO THE EXAMPLE
            </p></mat-dialog-content><mat-dialog-actions _ngcontent-lda-c13="" align="end" class="mat-dialog-actions"><button _ngcontent-lda-c13="" mat-button="" mat-dialog-close="" class="mat-button mat-button-base" ng-reflect-dialog-result="" type="button"><span class="mat-button-wrapper">Close</span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple="" ng-reflect-centered="false" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></button></mat-dialog-actions></div></app-factiondialog></mat-dialog-container>
```

I believe the upper section should say:

```
<mat-dialog-container aria-modal="true" class="mat-dialog-container faction-dialog ng-tns-c12-2 ng-trigger ng-trigger-dialogContainer ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1" id="mat-dialog-0" role="dialog" style="transform: none;">
```

but I'm not sure since I haven't gotten this to work. I've followed the documentation:

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig

I'm not sure if there's something I need to add in my app module or somewhere else.

Per the request of Mr. Khan:

faction2.component.ts:

```
openDialog(faction): void{



    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FactiondialogComponent, {panelClass: 'faction-dialog'})

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            console.log("dialog closed");
        });
}
```

Screen with modal open:
[image]

HTML Inspect Element

```
<mat-dialog-container aria-modal="true" class="mat-dialog-container ng-tns-c12-4 ng-trigger ng-trigger-dialogContainer ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1" id="mat-dialog-2" role="dialog" style="transform: none;"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-portal": ""
}--><app-factiondialog _nghost-yis-c13="" class="ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-yis-c13="" class="dialogCard"><h2 _ngcontent-yis-c13="" class="mat-dialog-title"></h2><mat-dialog-content _ngcontent-yis-c13="" class="mat-typography mat-dialog-content"><p _ngcontent-yis-c13=""></p></mat-dialog-content><mat-dialog-actions _ngcontent-yis-c13="" align="end" class="mat-dialog-actions"><button _ngcontent-yis-c13="" mat-button="" mat-dialog-close="" class="mat-button mat-button-base" ng-reflect-dialog-result=""><span class="mat-button-wrapper">Close</span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple=""></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></button></mat-dialog-actions></div></app-factiondialog></mat-dialog-container>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to add your own custom class to style the material modal, then firstly passes your custom class to the `panelClass` key in your modal this way:

```
this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddCustomComponent,{
    panelClass: 'custom-dialog-container', //======> pass your class name
});
this.dialogRef.afterClosed();
```

Once that's done, all you gotta do is style your modal by using your class and other models won't be affected. For example, you can remove the padding and margin this way.

```
/*Material Dialog Custom Css*/ 
.custom-dialog-container .mat-dialog-container{
    padding: 0;
}

.custom-dialog-container .mat-dialog-container .mat-dialog-content{
    margin: 0;
}
/*---------------------------*/
```

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing here:
```
 dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.data = {faction};
    dialogConfig.panelClass = ".faction-dialog";


    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FactiondialogComponent, dialogConfig)
```

?

Comment: Try removing the dot from the classname  ```  dialogConfig.panelClass = ".faction-dialog";

Comment: can you see your class added to the modal if you check with inspect elements?

Comment: No change. the issue seems to be that the mat-dialog-container isn't getting updated. But I have no idea why.

Comment: I cannot see the class added with the inspect element, that's also included in my write up

<mat-dialog-container aria-modal="true" class="mat-dialog-container ng-tns-c12-2 ng-trigger ng-trigger-dialogContainer ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1" id="mat-dialog-0" role="dialog" style="transform: none;">

Comment: try my approach

Comment: openDialog(faction): void{

 const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FactiondialogComponent, {panelClass: 'faction-dialog'})

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
   console.log("dialog closed");
  });
}

This didn't cause the element class to be added to the modal

Comment: Is the modal opening?

Comment: Yes, the modal opens but the html doesn't show the added panelClass as far as I can tell.

<mat-dialog-container aria-modal="true" class="mat-dialog-container ng-tns-c12-3 ng-trigger ng-trigger-dialogContainer ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1" id="mat-dialog-1" role="dialog" style="transform: none;">

Comment: add screen shot of your modal and modal markup shown by inspect element

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dialog-custom-params here is a stackblitz with working example of your approach and mines as well. you can comment one and try the other both of them are working perfectly.

Comment: Not really sure what changed but I copied your stackblitz code over and it worked. So thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The panelClass gets added to the parent of the dialog container, so the space is what I was missing:

```
.custom-dialog-container <<space>> .mat-dialog-container{
   padding: 0;
}
```

Also use ng-deep or put the style in the root stylesheet, not the component
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add the only solution that worked for me. I tried all approaches in this thread and many others, but nothing would affect the dialog. Eventually I realised that the dialog does not use the properties background or background-color, but --mdc-dialog-container-color. Applying the color to this property directly worked for me.

styles.scss (Global stylesheet)

```
.confirmationPopUp .mat-mdc-dialog-container {
  --mdc-dialog-container-color: #015945;
  color: mat.get-color-from-palette($my-primary, 50);
}
```

The component's .ts

```
  openPopUp(
    enterAnimationDuration: string,
    exitAnimationDuration: string
  ): void {
    this.dialog.open(PopUp, {
      width: '250px',
      enterAnimationDuration,
      exitAnimationDuration,
      panelClass: 'confirmationPopUp',
    });
  }
```

The classes
enterAnimationDuration: string,
exitAnimationDuration: string
simply animate the dialog open/close.

Hope this helps someone else! The above solutions probably worked at some point, but not anymore it seems :)

Answer (score 1):

Great answer above, but I wanted to just extend it by saying that the `MatDialogConfig` can also be passed via some config object.

i.e. I passed in custom class `SingleViewDialog` for my scenario, where the `my-custom-maximize`  `padding` override was added to our `mat-dialog.scss` override file:

```js
export interface SingleViewDialog {
  examUID: string;
  examData: TrendOctExam;
  layoutMode: Layout;  
}

public launchSingleView(examUID: string, examData: TrendOctExam) {
    const config: MatDialogConfig<SingleViewDialog> = {};
    config.hasBackdrop = true;
    config.disableClose = false;
    config.panelClass = 'my-custom-maximize';
    const mode: Layout = 'volume2d';
    config.data = { examUID, examData, layoutMode: mode};
    
    const dialogRef = this.matDialog.open(OCTThreeDSingleComponent, config );   //*** INJECT HERE ***
    
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(_ => this.viewStateService.updateLayoutMode('glaucoma'));
  }
```